# Open sqlite in readonly directly from assets

Tags: android, sqlite

I've found a lot of solutions to about how its possible to copy a database from assets to /data/data/tld.c.u/databases/ - But is it absolutely impossible to just open the database in readonly and query its content?

I have a rather large database i'm distributing with the app and its kind of a waste if the database must be copied out of the assets folder.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9109728/265167

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But is it absolutely impossible to just open the database in readonly and query its content?

Yes.

> I have a rather large database i'm distributing with the app and its kind of a waste if the database must be copied out of the assets folder.

Consider not distributing it with the app, but rather downloading it on first run, or using Google Play's new [APK expansion files](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/expansion-files.html) facility.

Comment: WHY is it not possible? Just because the Android API doesn't expose the correct methods? Or an actual design decision?

Comment: @SystemParadox: Because SQLite needs a file.