# Open SQLite Database directly from assets folder

Tags: android, sqlite, assets

A related Question is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9911004/open-sqlite-in-readonly-directly-from-assets). The tutorials show how to copy the database, but I want to open it directly, So I started with this code but it seems that there is an error that I wasn't able to know

```
SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("file:///android_asset/quiz.sqlite", null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
```

I can create a database and work on it and I can copy an existing database an work on it, But how to open it directly from the assets folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I want to open it directly

That is not possible, sorry. An asset is not a file. It is an entry in the ZIP archive that makes up an APK. SQLite has no means of working with an asset. `file:///android_asset/` is a hack for use with `WebView`; it does not work for arbitrary other pieces of code.

Comment: Thank you soooooo much, This is completely logical, Thanks :) :) :)